# Occurrence of number in array,with complexity log n algorithm and c

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, division, find-occurrences

hi genius i wish you good day
**Situation:**

```
T [M] an array sorts in ascending order.

Write an algorithm that calculates the number of occurrences of an integer x in the array T[M].

the number of comparison of x to the elements of T, must be of order log n
```

**My attempt is:**

```
def Occurrence(T,X,n):{
   
 
       if ( n=0 ){ return 0;}
        else { 

            Occurrence(T,X,n/2);

            if( T[n]==X ){  return 1+Occurrence(T,x,n/2); }
            else { return Occurrence(T,x,n/2); }

 
 }the end of code
complexity is :
                   0 if n=0
we have      O(n)={
                   1+O(n/2) if n>0
O(n)=1+1+1+....+O(n/2^(n))=n+O(2/2^(n))
when algorithm stopp if{existe k  n=2^(k),so   O(n)=n+1 } 
n/2^(n)=1)  =>   O(n)=log(n)+1, so you think my code is true ?
</pre>
```

Comment: 1. Binary Search for the first occurrence 2. Binary Search for the last occurrence. What is the problem with that?

Comment: first of all thank you for reacting.the situation Not saying first occurrence,i want all occurrence,I ask if these answer is responding to question or exist other answer to solve this problem or my attempt are not correct .

Comment: Your code currently fails to achieve the log(N) complexity in the case where the array has ~N occurences of the number you are searching for since in such case you need to perform ~N additions.  Also I'm not sure about the `else {return Occurence; }` depending on a language this is either not possible or returning a pointer to a function which probably isn't what you wanted.

Comment: thank you i've edited else {return Occurrence; },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the array is sorted

```
import bisect 

T = [1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7]
x = 4
right = bisect.bisect(T, x)
if(right == 0 or T[right - 1] != x):
    print("Count:0")
else:
    left = bisect.bisect_left(T, x)
    print("Count:", right - left)
```

2Log(n)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [binary search variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Duplicate_elements) that give the leftmost and the rightmost indices of  needed element, then return `index_difference + 1`

You can use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` in C++ STL, `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` in Python, similar functions if available, or implement pseudocode from Wiki citation.